# How to get scrollable div currentScrollY and totalScrollHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Here is my test code:

```html
<div id="scrollable" style="width:100%; height:100px; overflow: scroll">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dolorum esse,
  illum nostrum placeat quia? Animi corporis explicabo modi neque porro possimus
  quos totam. Accusamus ad aliquam animi, aperiam atque beatae consectetur
  debitis deleniti dignissimos doloremque doloribus ducimus ea error est eveniet
  fugit id iste itaque mollitia nostrum officia omnis optio quam quidem saepe
  sapiente ullam voluptatibus. A ad aliquam at aut, blanditiis commodi
  consectetur consequuntur delectus dignissimos ducimus ea esse est fuga fugiat,
  fugit illo inventore ipsa iusto laboriosam libero minima minus nesciunt nulla
  officia quaerat quam quidem quo recusandae reprehenderit similique soluta
  tempora, temporibus ut vel veritatis vero voluptatem. Ab culpa dolore eveniet
  exercitationem explicabo incidunt itaque laudantium molestiae nisi nobis
  nostrum, numquam possimus quam, quas quis, quisquam recusandae sed voluptatem.
  Deleniti esse iure nisi odio ullam. Autem ducimus eius enim inventore placeat
  possimus repudiandae voluptates? A adipisci cumque doloribus eligendi, eos
  eveniet harum laborum minus nam optio quae sed voluptas voluptates.
  Accusantium architecto, at dolor dolore eligendi incidunt ipsa, ipsum iure
  mollitia, nam nesciunt quo repellendus reprehenderit rerum sapiente similique
  voluptas. Eos laborum optio quibusdam voluptatum. Deserunt dolor doloribus
  enim minus praesentium reiciendis soluta tenetur. Ad consectetur consequuntur
  cumque iure molestias nam perferendis placeat quibusdam soluta, voluptatum!
</div>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
></script>
<script>
  var scrollable = document.querySelector("#scrollable");
  $(scrollable).on("scroll", ev => {
    console.log(`container scroll top:${$(scrollable).scrollTop()}`);
    console.log(`container scroll height:${$(scrollable).height()}`);
  });
</script>
```

I'm confused, when i scroll to scrollable div bottom, the scroll top != scroll height

Answer (score 0):

This should be correct.
`container scroll height` is the height of the window.
`container scroll top` is how far from the top of the content you've scrolled.

So if I load your content in my browser, and the `container scroll height` = 100, and I make the window narrower, then my `container scroll height` is still 100, I haven't changed the height of the window.  But now you can scroll further down, so your `container scroll top` could change as you scroll further down.